# How can I invert a media query using the NOT operator?

Tags: css, media-queries

How would I invert the following media query? I.e. not (A or B), alternatively not A and not B:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 512px), only screen and (max-height: 512px) { }`

Simply doing `@media screen and not (max-width: 512px), screen and (max-height: 512px) { }`  does not work.

Comment: Why not use `min-width` and `min-height`? Or not use anything at all, since those queries would only affect styles below those values?

Comment: To be clear are you wanting the media query to apply everywhere except when the screen is 512px wide *and* tall, or except when it is 512px wide *or* 512px tall?

Comment: To be clear I want the query to apply if not (max width <= 512 or max height <= 512)

Comment: @TylerH I guess that means except when it is <= 512px wide or <= 512px tall

Comment: I tried Boolean algebra.  It can't be done precisely with CSS Level 3.

Note that the 'comma' (`,`) 'operator', whilst effectively an `or` operator, is lowest precedence of all - it actually merely seperates a list of media queries, for which if any are matched the inner rules are applied.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @disinfor and @TylerH

`@media only screen and (min-width: 513px) and (min-height: 513px) {}`

does the trick

Comment: What happens when you use the browser's zoom feature, then resize the window so the width in logical pixels is, say, `512.5`?  Does anything fall down the gap?  (Are you lacking rules for the gap between `512px` and `513px`?)  If that could be an issue, I suggest minimums of `512.01px` (much lower than that and some browsers will round the value and you'll have an overlap instead).

Answer (score 1):

Note—this currently does not work in Chrome or Chromium-based browsers, as it relies on features in [Media Queries Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mq-syntax) which Chrome has yet to implement.

You would achieve your desired outcome, based on the code you've provided, by wrapping the conditions you want inside another set of parentheses.

In this demo, the red background in the media query applies all the time except when the conditions are met. So whenever the screen is below 500px in width *and* height, the conditions aren't met, and the original styles apply.

```css
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
}

@media screen and not ((max-width:500px) or (max-height: 500px)) {
    .container {
        background: red;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>
    This is some text!
    </p>
</div>
```

Be aware that `not screen` is *probably* not what you want, since that means it won't ever apply on a computer screen. In Media Queries Level 3, however, that is the required and only supported location to put the `not` keyword (to negate an entire query).

Comment: Yes, it's not what I meant, sorry. I've corrected. The logic isn't quite what I wanted in your answer, The logic I need is  ```@media screen and not ((max-width:500px) OR (max-height: 500px)) {}``` Is this possible?

Comment: @HalloweenMan Yep, it's as easy as changing the 'and' to 'or' in the parenthetical condition group :-). See my edit.

Comment: The answer isn't working for me. It remains green regardless of viewport size. I'm using Chrome Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: @HalloweenMan I've confirmed that, apparently Chrome only supports negation at the beginning of a media query rule (before the media type), rather than anywhere in the list. Not sure yet if that's by spec, or if Chrome is dragging their feet on support (or if Firefox is just early). Bummer, either way, because this is a really great feature to have!

Comment: It seems that Chrome still support the Level 3 of the specification. In the MDN we can read: *Note: In Level 3, the not keyword can't be used to negate an individual media feature expression, only an entire media query.* but in the Level 4 it should be ok to use not() like you did: https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mq-syntax

Comment: Reported it to this relevant Chromium bug - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=791028 might need to file as its own though since the linked bug specifies Mac. Not sure how Chromium sorts their bug reports by OS for features that should exist on both... thanks @TemaniAfif!

Comment: Thanks all for taking the effort, I've clicked the up arrow for the answer. However, readers need to be aware of patchy browser support for this at the moment. The alternative is my own answer.

Comment: @HalloweenMan I've updated the answer and added a caveat regarding lack of Chrome support. I'll try to keep track of its progress in getting added to Chromium/Blink, and update the answer again whenever that happens.